# Create Custom Control to Contain Other Custom Controls

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, custom-controls

I am creating an app which should guide the user through steps as can be seen in the below screenshot:

[image]

```
  <Step fx:id="selectConnectionStep" source="SelectConnection" stepLabel="Step 1 : Select a Connection" />
  <Step fx:id="selectSObjectStep" source="SelectSObject" stepLabel="Step 2 : Select an SObject" />
  <Step fx:id="selectActionStep" stepLabel="Step 3 : Select an Action">
      <VBox GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <Action actionLabel="test" onAction="#test" />
          <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
          </GridPane.margin>
      </VBox>
  </Step>
```

In the app I have more scenes configured to work that way so I want to design it in a way it will be easy to maintain.

I have created Custom Control called "Step" (which is basically extends **GridPane**)

Each "Step" has title, loadingIcon and the Inner Component.

In the first two steps, i load the inner component using the 'source' attribute I created. I just give the name of the Component's FXML file. In the code I just load the FXML and put the component inside the right place.
However, as can be seen in the 3rd step, I try to just populate the Inner Component as the Step child. As can be seen this is working, however I want Step to inject its child inside the right place without specifying any details of where to put it inside the grid.

I.e.

```
<Step fx:id="selectActionStep" stepLabel="Step 3 : Select an Action">
      <VBox>
          <Action actionLabel="test" onAction="#test" />
      </VBox>
</Step>
```

If I just don't specify any details, the component will go inside the GridPane on the top left corner.

**The question is how can a Custom Control manipulate its FXML child elements ?
Is it also ok that i extend GridPane ?**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is adding a `ListChangeListener` to the child list after adding the "standard" elements, e.g.

```
private static final Insets MARGIN = new Insets(10, 10, 15, 15);

...

// add standard elements...

getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
             for (Node n : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                 GridPane.setColumnSpan(2);
                 GridPane.setRowIndex(1);
                 GridPane.setMargin(MARGIN);
             }
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast respond.
Is it possible to expose this Step control inside the scene builder and then also drag the inner component inside the Step control? also restrict the user to drag only one inner component inside ? or it's much more complicated ?

Comment: @RonDaniel I'm pretty sure this kind of behavior is impossible when extending `GridPane`, since IF scenebuilder allows this (last time I tried it had only limited support), then it'l consider `Step` a `Pane` and allow adding a arbitrary number of children... You may have better luck extending `Control` and adding a property for the "custom contents", but IDK if scenebuilder supports adding something to such a property at all...

Comment: I am not sore yet but I think you really helped me out. the reason is because I wanted to introduce new element StepGroup. so we can have Steps Under StepGroup. StepGroup will be used when there are many steps and they cannot go into one scene. so I will change scenes based on StepGroup. I will have StepManager which will hold this StepGroups and manipulate the UI accordingly. thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this post which introduces another solution:

[How to add node to another node's child in FXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595320/how-to-add-node-to-another-nodes-child-in-fxml)